# How to segregate display output of a binary in 2 different files?

Tags: shell, unix

I Have a Shell script which executes couple of binary files infinitely . My Task is to redirect the output displayed by these binary files into a log file with timestamp (YY-MM-DD). This task is pretty easy , However problem arises when the day changes. This is my problem -- If a particular binary file is in the process of execution (not completed yet) and day changes , the output should displayed should be logged in 2 different files with different timestamps. For Eg: -

```
    while true; do
      if (current_date = new_date); then
        execute binary >> log.out_$current_date
    // If binary is still in the process of execution how to redirect in 2 files ???
      else 
        execute binary >> log.out_$new_date
      fi
    done
```

Required Output is :: output of file on current_date to be logged in current log file and output of file on new date to be logged in new file
..... Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Just create a further script that read from the `stdout` of your binary and check for the date after every single line read

```
(source of outputdatescript.sh)

#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

    # example made with unix data, replace it with your date string generator
    date=$(date "+%s")

    echo $line >> file.$date

done;
```

then the command in your main script must be subst from

```
execute binary >> log.out_$current_date
```

to

```
execute binary | outputdatescript.sh
```